# What are the advantages of using controller as syntax instead of $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, mean-stack

One of the things that different Angular learning materials seem to be doing differently is passing variables. What is the difference between using $scope or the "someCtrl as some" syntax? What are the advantages? Should I stick with always using one of them or there are certain scenarios when using one of them is better than the other?

Comment: It makes scoping much more clear, and also if you plan on using angular 2, that is how the syntax is set up so it's not bad to learn.

Comment: see John Papa's style guide, for some more explanation of why controller as: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of "Controller as" in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755929/what-is-the-advantage-of-controller-as-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

[Todd Motto](http://toddmotto.com/) has some very good articles on this!

[Digging into Angular’s “Controller as” syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)
[A better way to $scope, angular.extend, no more “vm = this”](http://toddmotto.com/a-better-way-to-scope-angular-extend-no-more-vm-this/)