# What is the advantage of "Controller as" in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

What is the advantage of using "Controller as" syntax in Angular? Is it just to create an alias for a controller or does it have some other technical reasons behind the scenes?

I am new to Angular and want to know more about this syntax.

Comment: Above all it better prepares you for Angular2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`controllerAs`-syntax has multiple advantages:

**Clartiy**

Consider the following example:

```
<div ng-controller="containerController">
    <h2>Improve your life!</h2>
    <p ng-controller="paragraphController">
        We talk about {{topic}} a lot, but do we really understand it? 
        Read this article to enhance your knowledge about {{topic}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Just by reading this piece of code, you can not tell where `topic` comes from. Does it belong to the `containerController`, to the `paragraphController` or is it just a random floating scope variable from sone input above?

By using `controllerAs` it is very clear:

```
<div ng-controller="containerController as container">
    <h2>Improve your life!</h2>
    <p ng-controller="paragraphController as paragraph">
        We talk about {{paragraph.topic}} a lot, but do we really understand it? 
        Read this article to enhance your knowledge about {{paragraph.topic}}
    </p>
</div>
```

You can immediately see that `topic` is a property of `paragraphController`. This makes code a lot more readable overall, as it forces the developer to make clear who the functions and variables in the `scope` belong to.

**Binding to properties**

When you are using the old `controller` syntax, strange things can happen when you have multiple bindings in different scopes to the "same" variable. Consider this example:

```
<form ng-controller="myFormController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="somefield">

    <div ng-controller="someOtherController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="somefield">
    </div>
</form>
```

It looks like both `input`s are bound to the same variable. They are not. Everything looks like it works fine when you edit the first `input` first, but as soon as you edit the second one, they won't sync up anymore. This has to do with the way scope-inheritance and binding work([and there is an excellent answer on this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)). This does not happen when you bind to object properties (aka when there is a `.` in your `ng-model`-attribute). With `controllerAs` you bind to properties of the controller objects anyways, so it naturally solves that problem:

```
<form ng-controller="myFormController as myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.somefield">

    <div ng-controller="someOtherController as other">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.somefield">
    </div>
</form>
```

**It gets rid of `scope`(mostly)**

The use of `scope` to create bindings to `controller`s in old angular code is hard to read, hard to understand and completely unnecessary if you use `controllerAs`. You no longer have to inject `scope` into every single `controller`, in fact you will probably not inject it in any in most applications (you still need to do so if you want to use the angular event system). This results in cleaner controller-code with less strange boilerplate.

**It prepares for Angular 2**

[In angular 2, `scope` will be gone and we will write everything as components](http://blog.ionic.io/angular-2-series-components/). Using `controllerAs` lets you work without `scope` and forces you to think more component-oriented, thus preparing you (and the applications you eventually will want to migrate) for the 2.0 update.

Comment: @LionC - I just have to say that this is a very clear and concise explanation. I was asked about the reasons for moving from the use of "$scope" to "this" syntax in a job interview, and I immediately mentioned the "Controller As" syntax. The guy seemed quite pleased with my response.

Comment: @LionC Thanks for pointing out the use $scope if in case you have to add event listeners than the $scope is useful. Thanks for the differences.