# Why does ng-click on checkbox update the value of array after function is called?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have an array with persons who have scores. I display with the list of persons with their scores and a checkbox. When the user checks the checkbox, I total all scores that are checked.:
http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/hwutbgv3/16

However, the totals are one check behind since it seems that when Angular executes the function contained in `ng-click`, it has not updated the value of `ng-model`.

**How can I get Angular to update the value FIRST, and then execute the function?**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'score'"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.isChecked" ng-click="updateTotals()"/> {{person.name}} = {{person.score}} ({{person.isChecked}}) 

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>{{message}}</div>
    <div>total score of checked persons: {{total}}</div>
</div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $window) {

    $scope.debug = '';
    $scope.total = 0;

    $scope.persons = [
        {score: 1, name: 'Jim', isChecked: true},
        {score: 2, name: 'Joe', isChecked: false},
        {score: 3, name: 'Angie', isChecked: true}
    ];

    $scope.updateTotals = function() {
        $scope.total = 0;
        for(var x=0; x < $scope.persons.length; x++) {
            var person = $scope.persons[x];
            if(person['isChecked']) {
                $scope.total += person['score'];   
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.updateTotals()
}
```

Comment: I think you can use ng-change instead of ng-click.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `ng-click` is trigger before the `ng-model` changes so you need to use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`.

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'score'">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.isChecked" ng-change="updateTotals(person)"/>
    .....
</li>
```

here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jgydy5cp/)

---

Also you can get rid of the controller `updateTotals()` and manage it inside the view like

define total in controller

```
// using a object because we need this inside `ng-repeat` which create a child scope, otherview we need to call it as $parent.total in the view.
$scope.all = {
    total: 0
};
```

in html

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'score'" ng-init="person.isChecked ? (all.total = all.total+person.score) : return">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.isChecked" ng-change="person.isChecked ? (all.total = all.total+person.score) : (all.total = all.total-person.score)"/>
        {{person.name}} = {{person.score}} ({{person.isChecked}})
    </li>
</ul>
```

use `ng-init` to calculate the total when initial phase

```
...ng-init="person.isChecked ? (all.total = all.total+person.score) : return"...
```

add or deduct the score when changing the checkbox value

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.isChecked" ng-change="person.isChecked ? (all.total = all.total+person.score) : (all.total = all.total-person.score)"/>
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rCZcsAwvjNpb6Ga28m9M?p=preview)

---

If you feel like the `html` is bit messy then move the conditions and updating the total to the `controller` as

call `updateTotal` on initial phase and the checkbox change phase and pass the arguments *(person & `true/false` to indicate the initial phase or not)*

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'score'" ng-init="updateTotal(person, true)">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.isChecked" ng-change="updateTotal(person, false)"/>
    {{person.name}} = {{person.score}} ({{person.isChecked}})
</li>
```

in controller

```
$scope.updateTotal = function(person, isInitPhase) {
    if (isInitPhase) {
        if (person.isChecked) {
            $scope.total += person.score;
        }
    } else {
        if (person.isChecked) {
          $scope.total += person.score;
        } else {
            $scope.total -= person.score;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WIzPU1m1bZSLhXFKSzsx?p=preview)

**I choose last one because I feel it lot cleaner.**

Comment: while this works, it is still kind of an anti pattern

Answer (score 0):

Do not update view-data yourself, use data binding for that. Just rename your `updateTotals`-function to `getTotal` and make it return the calculated total:

```
$scope.getTotal = function() {
    var total = 0;

    for(var x=0; x < $scope.persons.length; x++) {
        var person = $scope.persons[x];
        if(person['isChecked']) {
            total += person['score'];   
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

and change your template to show `getTotal()`:

```
<div>total score of checked persons: {{getTotal()}}</div>
```

Now you can remove your `ng-click` on your checkbox and let angular do the work for you.

On a different note, I would recommend to look into [controllerAs-syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) and to start using it, [it has a number of different advantages, including readability and removing $scope from your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755929/what-is-the-advantage-of-controller-as-in-angular/32756679#32756679).