# Angular best practices: pass a $scope to a service or pass a computed value object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Imagine a case where you have a data service which query a database. For working properly you have to deal with a several $scope variables:

```
$scope.trackerIds, //Array of objects
$scope.dateTo,
$scope.dateFrom,
```

Is it best:
1) to compute a value object inside the controller then pass it to a service

for example:

```
var vo = {
    trackers: _.map(trackersIds, function(trackerId, key){
        return {
            trackerId: trackerId,
            geoip : $scope.trackers[trackerId].geoip
        }
    }),
    dates:[$scope.dateFrom.toISOString(), $scope.dateTo.toISOString()],
}

var dataPromise = dataservice.getTracesBuckets(vo);
```

2) Or send directly the $scope to the service

```
var dataPromise = dataservice.getTracesBuckets($scope);
```

In the first case there will be logic in the controller to collect and arrange $scope variables.
In the second case the service will be coupled to the controller because he must know about the $scope structure to call the right variables.

I am in a "what is less worth" case, so I wonder if I am not missing something important. I am completely rebuilding my architecture thanks to [Johnpapa Angular Style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) but there is no help on this.

Comment: It is best practice not to use `$scope` for your controller data at all. Use controller-as

Comment: Yep you are right, I have not implemented that yet. But the problem stays the same, does not?

Comment: @LionC, Can you provide some justification/Ref material for your comment. It sounds helpful!

Comment: Think of service methods as API's. They take specific parameters and responds to them. Its better not to pass the `$scope` to service and good to pass the parameters that are needed for the service method.

Comment: @RayonDabre [I wrote a longer answer about that topic once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755929/what-is-the-advantage-of-controller-as-in-angular/32756679#32756679)

Comment: @xyz very interesting. I tend to think the same about the analogy with an API. Have you a also a link reference to post as an answer ?
Plus, is the $scope variables manipulation in my example is considered as logic code?

Comment: @DanielN: Sorry, I do not have a reference. IMO, variables manipulation also can be considered as logic code(in case, if you have conditionals to build the object for the service). In my experience, I used have prepare methods in service to create the data for service and only pass the required params to the prepare methods. I like to keep the controller as simple as possible(ie: with out logic, formatters, etc)

Comment: @LionC While it might be better to use `controllerAs` instead of `$scope` to be better for the future, but they are just style preference in current state. It is not right to pass `vm` into a service even you use `controllerAs`, just to answer OP's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services are View-Less components,
It's always wrong to pass view-model to a service...

You Must use your Controller to transform view-model in model, then, use the model in service (ex, data access via ajax)...

---

UPDATE: 
according to the angular specs, The Controller is a BL-Component, the difference with services is that in controllers we have to put the only-business-logic that the view needs to work.... In service, instead, we have to put all business logic that is view-less... in other words, the controller must only transform the Domain-Model in View-Model and viceversa! In your example you pass the $scope object to the service, doing this you link the service with the view and this is a bad practice, if something changes in the $scope you have to change the service too! Use Ctrl to transform vm in m

Comment: So code in a controller to handle some $scope variables is not considered as logic code? (because it is "forbidden" to put logic code in a controller)

Comment: @DanielN It is business logic which is 'forbidden'.

Comment: @DanielN All code is expressing logic. It is business logic(the "core" logic of an application) that should be kept out of controllers as much as possible

Comment: Yep, controller is a Business Logic Component, but the $scope isn't!
$scope is intimately linked with the view...

You need to use the controller to manipulate the $scope object...

By the way, this is just a Design Pattern, you can do everything you want to do!

Comment: I am a bit confused with the two last comments above. You says that controller is a Business Logic Component but @LionC says controllers have to avoid business code. Is the $scope variables manipulation in my example is considered as business code?

Comment: according to the angular specs, The Controller is a BL-Component, the difference with services is that in controllers we have to put the only-business-logic that the view needs to work.... In service, instead, we have to put all business logic that is view-less...

in other words, 
the controller must only transform the Domain-Model in View-Model and viceversa! 

In your example you pass the $scope object to the service, doing this you link the service with the view and this is a bad practice, if something changes in the $scope you have to change the service too!
Use Ctrl to transform vm in m

Comment: Thx you @Hitmands . This is very clear now. Could you past this comment in your answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Services should be business-logic units that are unaware of how (or by whom) they are used - so it would be an anti-pattern to pass your whole `$scope` to a service, when that service should not even know `$scope` exists.

Instead, define a clear contract for the business logic your service is performing, giving each function exactly the parameters it needs, in the simplest form possible.

In the end this boils down to a basic principle of MVC(/[MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)) - decoupling Model and View as much as possible.

Comment: I think I begin to understand. But where should go my code which build my `vo` object?

Answer (score 0):

I think the convenient method is:

couple your code in your controller then pass it to service:

in your "constructor" of controller

```
var vo = doJob($scope.trackers, $scope.dateFrom, $scope.dateTo)
var dataPromise = dataservice.getTracesBuckets(vo);
```

and in your function in controller

```
doJob(trackers, dateFrom, dateTo) {
    var vo = {
        trackers: _.map(trackersIds, function(trackerId, key){
            return {
                trackerId: trackerId,
                geoip : trackers[trackerId].geoip
            }
        }),
        dates:[dateFrom.toISOString(), dateTo.toISOString()]
    }
}
```