# Creating constants for paths and links in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Everywhere throughout my website we got links and paths.

```
http://localhost:3001/controllers/getUsers
http://localhost:3001/controllers/getHouses

http://localhost:8080/assets/img/mypic.png
http://localhost:8080/assets/img/yourpic.png
```

This is a problem when we switch to production server.

How would you create a "constant" with the path in angular?

```
const controllerPath = "http://localhost:3001/controllers/"
const imagePath = "http://localhost:8080/assets/img/"
```

So we can use them in all pages?

I read about these two:

```
app.constant('controllerPath', 'http://localhost:3001/controllers/');
app.value('controllerPath', 'http://localhost:3001/controllers/');
```

But then you have to remember to send all paths to all controllers on all pages.

We could put them in $rootScope but then you have to transfer that one to all pages.

Isnt there any "settings" or something similar in Angular where you can setup global constants?

Comment: You could use a "main" controller that injects the constant.

Comment: Bergur im not sure I understand.  Would that be a controller called on each page to set the constants into that pages scope?

Comment: Controller scopes inherit from `$rootScope`, so if you attach it as a property on `$rootScope` they would all be able to access it.

Comment: @kicken yes but as you see in my question, then I have to send $rootscope to every single controller/page.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard You don't have to inject `$rootScope` specifically.  The `$scope` already provided to controllers would work, and your views would have access via it.

Comment: @kicken nope I tried already. Unless you inject it `app.controller("myController", function ($scope, $rootScope, etc..)` then you will just get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined` so you have to do that with every controller on every page, and we got a lot.  Thats why it sucks that there are no true "global constants" in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach your constants to the `$rootScope` service which will make them automatically available to any inherited scopes, such as those created for your controllers.  Then you can simply access them as properties of your controller's `$scope` without having to separately inject `$rootScope`.

```js
angular
 .module('demoApp', ['ngRoute'])
 .controller('page1Controller', ['$scope', function($scope){
  console.log('Asset Prefix: ' + $scope.assetPrefix);
 }])
 .controller('page2Controller', ['$scope', function($scope){
  console.log('Controllers Prefix: ' + $scope.controllersPrefix);
 }]);

angular.module('demoApp').config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
 $routeProvider.when('/page1', {
  controller: 'page1Controller'
  , controllerAs: 'vm'
  , template: '<p>Assets are located at: {{assetPrefix}}</p><a href="#/page2">What about controllers?</a>'
 });
 $routeProvider.when('/page2', {
  controller: 'page2Controller'
  , controllerAs: 'vm'
  , template: '<p>Controllers are located at: {{controllersPrefix}}</p><a href="#/page1">What about assets?</a>'
 });
 $routeProvider.otherwise('/page1');
}]);

angular.module('demoApp').run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
 $rootScope.assetPrefix = 'http://localhost:8080/assets';
 $rootScope.controllersPrefix = 'http://localhost:3001/controllers';
}]);

jQuery(function($){
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['demoApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the good example kicken!!.  Can I ask what does this one do? `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)` and what is the advantage of `controllerAs: 'vm'` (other than writing vm.whatever instead of $scope.whatever?

Comment: [html5Mode(false)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) prevents angular from using the [pushState/popState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) API's and using [controllerAs makes variable access clearer and can remove the need to use `$scope` in many cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755929/what-is-the-advantage-of-controller-as-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions for that:

- either use `$rootScope` for all your constant
  For exemple : $rootScope.controllerPath = ... 
  and inject $rootScope on every controller; that is a common usage.
- either use the localStorage with that great lib
  https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

You inject $localStorage and use it as $rootScope.

It s a cleaner solution in my point of view

Comment: Ahhh $localStorage. didnt know that one - I am gonna check that out right now.   Just strange that webpack compiles everything into one big fat js file, but does not make it possible to set constants for that file.

Comment: Okie - got it, would be very useful but you still have to inject it into every controller and page.  So you might as well just use $rootScope.   Anyway thanks for showing it to me :)

Comment: there is no magical solution. in both solution; you need to inject $rootScope to use global variable. This is not very clean; as $rootScope is your main $scope. ;) the father of all scopes ;)