# Get undefined when reading $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, scope, ng-controller

I'm trying to read the variable `accessCode` in my form in a Angular (1.6.8) function but I only get `undefined`.

**The HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="redeem()" ng-controller="SubscriptionCtrl as subscription">
   <input class="text-uppercase" type="number" ng-maxlength="6" placeholder="Indtast kode" ng-model="accessCode" />
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark-green" value="Indløs" />
</form>
```

**The Angular JS**

```
app.controller('SubscriptionCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
    function ($scope, $http, $templateCache) {

$scope.redeem = function () {
    console.log($scope.accessCode);
};
}]);
```

Any ideas why I can't read $scope.accessCode?

Comment: You did something like this:     angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('SubscriptionCtrl ', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  // ...
});    ????

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle or codepen?

Comment: ng-model="subscription.accessCode";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to revert your code back to using `$scope` since using controller as syntax is better ([See advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755929/what-is-the-advantage-of-controller-as-in-angular)). You have to bind not only your `ng-model` but also your `ng-submit` to your controller instance `subscription`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('SubscriptionCtrl',
    function() {
        var subscription = this;
        subscription.redeem = function() {
            console.log(subscription.accessCode)
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SubscriptionCtrl as subscription">
        <form ng-submit="subscription.redeem()">
            <input class="text-uppercase" type="number" ng-maxlength="6" placeholder="Indtast kode" ng-model="subscription.accessCode" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark-green" value="Indløs" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you forget to add the controller `as` section with `ng-model`,
>   because you used:

```
ng-controller="SubscriptionCtrl as subscription"
```

> So, in your ng-model, you have to use:

```
ng-model="subscription.accessCode"
```

> Also change `ng-submit="redeem()"` to
>   `ng-submit="subscription.redeem()"`
>
> So, the HTML section will be as follows:

```
    <form ng-submit="subscription.redeem()" ng-controller="SubscriptionCtrl as subscription">
       <input class="text-uppercase" type="number" ng-maxlength="6" placeholder="Indtast kode" ng-model="subscription.accessCode" />
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark-green" value="Indløs" />
    </form>
```

> In controller side implement as follows:

```
//creating a module
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

//registering the above controller to the module
app.controller("SubscriptionCtrl",['$scope',function ($scope){
  $scope.accessCode = "";
    $scope.redeem = function () {
    console.log($scope.accessCode);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: And how do I access it in my function? $scope.accessCode?

Comment: Access code is ok. $scope.redeem = function (collectionId) {
    console.log($scope.accessCode);
    ...
};

Comment: Have to defined controller like angular.module('myApp.controllers', []). controller('SubscriptionCtrl ', ['$scope', function ($scope) { // ... }); ?

Comment: I have defined the controller but left it out for simplicity. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

Might have missed `module` name in html.

**In `app.js` :**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('SubscriptionCtrl', function($scope) {
       console.log($scope.accessCode);
              .....
    });
```

Instead of using `as` .

**Directly inject the $scope into the controller.**

**In HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <form ng-submit="redeem(collection.Id)" ng-controller="SubscriptionCtrl">
       <input class="text-uppercase" type="number" ng-maxlength="6" placeholder="Indtast kode" ng-model="accessCode" />
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark-green" value="Indløs" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Follow [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Hope it helps..!